# DNS-address can't be found

Tags: dns, routing, port-forwarding, bind

I've put an NS-record on the DNS from my registrar, and pinging my DNS is working. But when i want to open a page from my webserver, i get the message "This site can’t be reached www.thoelen.tech’s server DNS address could not be found.".

I have the necessary records in my DNS, and the ports are open on my router.

Is there someone who maybe has an idea what's wrong with my setup?

Greetings and thanks in advance. Davy

Comment: You may wish double check that your registrar actually has your nameservers. Likewise, you may wish to post your BIND records. As it, it seems as if there is nothing pointing to your DNS server (no published records can be found).

Answer (score 1):

Your `ns02.thoelen.tech` nameserver isn't responding, and the `register.be` nameservers don't list `ns02.thoelen.tech` as authoritative, nor have any A records for thoelen.tech or www.thoelen.tech.

Are you actually intending to run a DNS server on your home ISP? This is what the current delegation seems to imply. This requires having both TCP and UDP port 53 to it. You'll also need a way to sync your zone files if you're mixing delegation between different servers.

I think you might to remove the `ns02.thoelen.tech` server and configure all your records from the `register.be` control panel instead.

Comment: My intention is to have my own dns server running at home. I want to host multiple websites (on default port 80 and 8080), but the sites are on different servers (Debian apache, Windows IIS, SharePoint,...).

Comment: You need to make sure register.be supports zone transfers and a master/slave setup and then have your home DNS server be a slave/master. Additionally you need to make your home DNS server reachable by opening the appropriate ports. Be aware your ISP may block such services as it's rare to host DNS at home.

Comment: I have a subscription with fixed ip and without blocked ports.
My router is forwarding each port to my DNS, so no blocks there.
I asked register.be for confirmation if they support zone transfers, waiting for an answer.